# How to Intercept angular 2 HTTP Calls using angular 4 HTTP interceptor?

Tags: angular, http, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I am trying to import a custom library which has **angular 2 HTTP calls**(http imported from Http) into an **Angular 4 Project**. in my library module, http calls are something like this.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class SampleService(){

constructor(public http: Http){}

sampleGetMethod(){
   this.http.get('api_link');
}

}
```

I am trying to intercept library HTTP calls using **Angular 4 HTTP Interceptor**, but I am unable to intercept these calls because in angular4, **Http is imported from HttpClient**;

**Is there any way of Intercepting old HTTP calls using new Angular  Interceptor ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by extending the Http class and override http methods (get, post,...).

**However, i would prefer updating you http to http client because the old http is being deprecated.**